# Capacitor Plugin development how to re-install in order to debug / test changes

Tags: android, ionic-framework, reload, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am working on a private Capacitor plugin for an ionic app. I managed to add it to my project (it now sits nicely in node_modules), but any changes I make, the plugin does not get re-installed in the Android build process.

Only thing I can think off is each time to either remove the Android project and add it or remove the plugin manually and reinstall it.
But since I am still developing this plugin, it almost seems impossible to test (as it contains physical device API's, I test in Android Studio)

Surely there must be a better way to automatically re-install my Capacitor plugin when I make code changes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [command](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-sync) `ionic capacitor sync` ?

Comment: That was something I did try, but turns out I was not quite following the developer workflow as well as I should have. 
More info I found here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/workflow

However, I keep having issues trying to add the local dev version of my plugin into my ionic vuejs project. No matter how hard I try, vue wont recognise the dependency. 
So I gave up and went for an oldskool Cordova plugin without issues.